# How can I dual boot Ubunutu alongside a corrupted Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

So here's the situation. While running CCleaner, something in my Windows files got deleted. After rebooting my PC, I got some bad news.

So, I ran the system repair to no avail. I had no applicable restore points, nor do I have my Windows 7 disc (my PC came preloaded). So, thankfully I remembered that I had Ubuntu on my flashdrive.

So, here's the situation now. I'm currently running Ubuntu on my flashdrive, however, I won't be getting a new PC for a few months (and I'm not going to repurchase Windows 7 in the mean time, since that'd be a waste), so I want to install Ubuntu so I can access my files and continue using my computer on Ubuntu in the mean time. I can't get into Windows, so I can't safely shrink my partition. I also don't have an external harddrive, so I can't really backup my files and risk doing it via Ubuntu.

So, what I want to do is install Ubuntu without affecting any of my Windows files, as I'd like to access them and eventually transfer them to my new builds. What are my current options, if any?

I'd appreciate any help.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I have another PC running Windows 7, so if I can somehow use that to fix my error, that'd be possible.

Comment: You would have to go to a Windows support forum for repairing your windows problem.  Try http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would this be the right forum to get my dualboot working in the meantime though?

Comment: Yes.  I'm tying in details... give me five minutes...

Comment: @Victory - take this free registry cleaner - but do a malware check first - in Windows 7 you may clean the registry files only, when datas are free of malware (avast, avira, anti-malwarebytes.org) The link for registry cleaner is here : http://www.heise.de/download/wise-registry-cleaner-1138583.html

Comment: Wish I could, but I can't boot up windows.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Ubuntu install features is to dual boot.  If you already have a partition you can use the option of something else

You would also have the option (which you are probably already using) to `Try Ubuntu`.  With this option you can use the gui partition manager, gparted to allocate space by resizing your partition.

From the live boot disk (again, what you appear to be using) you can back up your windows Files.  You can actually purchase a 60 or 120 gig USB stick for under $50.00 for your backup media.  There are also many other backup media options, such as USB drives.

Of course you already said you didn't want to change anything on your Windows, so that might be out of the question.

Resizing your partition and making space for a new Linux partition wouldn't change the data, it would just change the size of the windows partition.

You could also install a secondary drive and install Ubuntu on that drive.

As far as installing along size Windows, that's just as easy.  Run the install program and choose that option.  It'll give you a graphic slider and automatically make the partition size adjustment according to your specification.  It's relatively seamless.

The latter, by the way, also makes some changes to your computer.  If you don't have any other partition space available,  you will inadvertently be making the windows partition smaller.

Finally, when installing Ubuntu you will be installing a different boot manager.  You can boot into Windows with the Linux (grub) boot manager.  But you can't boot into Linux with the Windows Boot manager.

By the way, you could consider a full install of Ubuntu on an external drive.

Comment: But from my reading, it seems like using Ubuntu to manage your Windows partition is a bit risky. Is that true? I don't really have another harddrive currently.

Comment: I don't know where you heard this, but, it's my experience the Linux partition managers are very robust.  The fact that you appear to be locked out of using Windows tools to access and manage your system might confirm this to some degree.  I repair my client's windows machines.  But I use Linux for backing up, partitioning and just about everything that needs to be done short of finally performing the Windows install.  As I think of it, Microsoft's new uefi mode is a little tricky for some people.

Comment: So, there's not a very good chance the repartitioning of my windows drive with Ubuntu would mess any of my data up?

Comment: There's always some remote chance of loosing data, but Linux wouldn't mess it up.  You'd have a better chance of retaining your data using Linux.  The developers always stress backing up important data when working on drives.  I'm not proud to say it because backing up is very important.  But I've been working with Linux/Unix since the mid 80's (longer than anyone I know).  I have never lost any data.  I'm familiar with people that makes a mistake and format the wrong partition, or format the wrong hard drive.  But as far as the tools, using them correctly, problems are rare.

Comment: So how would I exactly resize the partition in Ubuntu. Would I go to the "more options" in the installer? I appreciate the help a lot by the way.

Comment: If the Installer recognizes your Windows (or other OS) install it will give you and option to `Install Ubuntu alongside them`.  On that option screen you will have a slider do decide how big you want to make you Windows partition.  Other than that, the installer doesn't have a partitioning manager... that one works fine.  As I mentioned above when booting to the Live disk you can use the actually `Try Ubuntu` option to run `gparted`, the partitioning manager freely resize and create your own partitioning.  The `Install Alongside` is probably more seamless and easier for a novice.

Comment: The option wasn't there. From what I researched, that's due to the fact that I don't have any free partition space. Which is why I was concerned in the first place. But it recognized my Windows, as the first option had a warning that said: "This will delete all files from previous operating system" or something to that affect. Let me go boot back up in Ubuntu (using separate pc currently) and I'll check gparted out.

Comment: Sounds like your Windows install is substantially corrupted.  One thing you might consider is a 16/32 gig pen drive.  They are pretty inexpensive [(32 Gig drive example at Office Depot)](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/801187/SanDisk-Cruzer-32GB-USB-20-Flash/?cm_mmc=PLA-_-Google-_-Data_Storage_Media-_-801187-VQ6-47886868556-VQ16-c-VQ17-pla-VQ18-online-VQ19-801187-VQ20-76860675716-VQ21-&gclid=Cj0KEQiAtri0BRDLoaCF95e7o_sBEiQA_pgRQyG8c0spb6WN3zyPGKdQ70t8IMY5z8adGNDeHwIxdrYaAhiz8P8HAQ).  Consider installing Ubuntu on to that drive.  The install process might even repair your Windows boot.

Comment: I'm currently doing the "Try Ubuntu" on a 16 Gigabyte flash drive. So should I try installing ubuntu onto the flash drive?

Comment: That's my recommendation.  But you can't use the same media for installing that you are installing to.  You'd have to have one Pen Drive (or DVD) for the install medium and a different medium to install to.

Comment: Could I put ubuntu install onto a disc and then install it onto the flashdrive? Or maybe a sd card? I'm planning on getting a 1 terrabyte external harddrive tomorrow though, so I think my plan is to do a full install on that external harddrive, use it until I get my new pc, clear ubuntu of the harddrive, run the "try ubuntu" from my flashdrive and use ubuntu to transfer all of my windows files to the harddrive, and use the harddrive to bring them to my new build. Bit of a mouthful, but does that sound like a solid plan?

Comment: The ubuntu install comes on an ISO and fits on a DVD.  Use the method you did to create your live USB for creating a Live DVD medium.  Then boot from the DVD and perform a normal install your pen drive.